# NotBlank validation error in float java (spring boot)

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, entity

I'm trying to develop an API with an order model and one of the requirements in my model is "price" which takes a float instead of a string

this is the model

```
package com.api.order_control.models;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Table(name = "TB_ORDER")
public class OrderModel implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private UUID id;
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 11)
    private String customerName;
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 15)
    private String phoneNumber;
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 25)
    private String address;
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String doorNumber;
    @Column(nullable = true, length = 5)
    private String block;
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 30)
    private String order;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Float price;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime registrationDate;

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getDoorNumber() {
        return doorNumber;
    }

    public void setDoorNumber(String doorNumber) {
        this.doorNumber = doorNumber;
    }

    public String getBlock() {
        return block;
    }

    public void setBlock(String block) {
        this.block = block;
    }

    public String getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(String order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    public Float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getRegistrationDate() {
        return registrationDate;
    }

    public void setRegistrationDate(LocalDateTime registrationDate) {
        this.registrationDate = registrationDate;
    }
}
```

this is the dto package

```
package com.api.order_control.dtos;

import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

public class OrderDto {
    @NotBlank
    private String customerName;
    @NotBlank
    private String phoneNumber;
    @NotBlank
    private String address;
    @NotBlank
    private String doorNumber;
    @NotBlank
    private String block;
    @NotBlank
    private String order;
    @NotBlank
    private Float price;

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String doorNumber() {
        return doorNumber;
    }

    public void doorNumber(String doorName) {
        this.doorNumber = doorName;
    }

    public String getBlock() {
        return block;
    }

    public void setBlock(String block) {
        this.block = block;
    }

    public String getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(String order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    public Float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

I created my post method in my controller, but when I test it in my postman I get this error in the terminal:

```
jakarta.validation.UnexpectedTypeException: HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank' validating type 'java.lang.Float'. Check configuration for 'price'
```

I understand that the problem is in float, but I can't understand what's wrong with this code.

update: controller

```
package com.api.order_control.controllers;


import com.api.order_control.dtos.OrderDto;
import com.api.order_control.models.OrderModel;
import com.api.order_control.services.OrderService;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
@RequestMapping("/order")
public class OrderController {

    final OrderService orderService;

    public OrderController(OrderService orderService) {
        this.orderService = orderService;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Object> saveOrder(@RequestBody @Valid OrderDto orderDto) {
        var orderModel = new OrderModel();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(orderDto, orderModel);
        orderModel.setRegistrationDate(LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC")));
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(orderService.save(orderModel));
    }
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself the question, what a _blank_ float would look like ...

Comment: How it should be?

Comment: The JavaDoc for `@NotBlank` specifically says, "Accpts `CharSequence`." `Float` is not a `CharSequence`.

Comment: Ehhmm ... I told you to ask _yourself_ that question. While thinking about it, you might come to the conclusion that a float cannot be blank.

Comment: So what would be the best way to validate a float?

Comment: What validation do you want to have on your float? As it is, you can check nullness (because it is a `Float` - with a capital F), and you can also check the value. What do you want?

Comment: I erasing my "price" from dto do I have to declare it in my controlle then? right? Since my model is being built based on my dto (as I showed in the updated code)

Comment: Would you know how I can pass the request body inside my setPrice in controller?

Comment: like:         orderModel.setPrice(I would like to know how to pass the request body here
);

Comment: You're trying to validate that a `Float` is "not blank", but that just doesn't make any sense at all. It's like validating that a circle has only 3 sides - the concept of "sides" doesn't apply to a circle. Similarly, the concept of "blankness" doesn't apply to a `Float`.

Comment: Perhaps you just need `@NotNull`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@NotNull` for `Float`. The [documentation for `@NotBlank`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/constraints/NotBlank.html) states:

> The annotated element must not be null and must contain at least one non-whitespace character. Accepts CharSequence.

So, as long as you don't use `@NotBlank` on a `String` or `Char` it won't work.

If you need additional validations on the value of the float, you can use `@Min`, `@Max`, `@Positive` and more.